# Do we have a left adjoint of $i^*$ for a closed immersion $i$?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, homological-algebra, derived-categories, adjoint-functors, derived-functors

Let $i: X\hookrightarrow Y$ be a closed immersion of varieties. We have the derived pullback functor $i^*: D^b_{coh}(Y)\to D^b_{coh}(X)$.

My questions is: can we construct a left adjoint of $i^*$ in this case? It seems that the left adjoint is not given in the general construction of Grothendieck's six functors.

Edit: Using Serre functors, I can find a left adjoint of $i^*$ in the case that Y is smooth Calabi-Yau and $X$ is also smooth. But I wonder if there is an answer without the Calabi-Yau condition.

Comment: I think that this is the case when the closed immersion is lci. Affine locally, it implies that $R/I$ is a perfect $R$-module.

Comment: The Calabi-Yau condition is absolutely irrelevant, if both $X$ and $Y$ are smooth (hence $X$ is l.c.i. in $Y$), as @Z.M explained in his comment.